# Unable to run Microsoft Office 2010 install file

Tags: installation, icons, microsoft-office-2010

This problem began when I noticed that the icons in the Windows 7 task bar for MS Word and Outlook were generic. I rebuilt the icon cache. Still not the right icons, but not the generic "document" icons either, and both are identical (to each other). The two programs seem to be *working* OK.

So then I tried to repair MS Office. I ran the setup file. It extracts the files, I get the splash screen, and then the message, "Setup has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available." with a "Close program" button. Microsoft does *not* notify me about a solution.

What I have tried: 1. running two other copies of the setup program; 2. doing an in-place re-install of Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling Office?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like something has "stuck" around from an earlier installation: either in the registry or the file system. You can spend quite a lot of time trying to re-install, uninstall etc. You could call Microsoft Support. They have some tools that are targeted to cleaning specific libraries, files, DLLs etc. Bear in mind, that might be a long call, so find some spare time.

What I usually do is:

1. Backup essential data.
2. Try restoring you OS to a point in time when Office ran well.
3. If that doesn't work, try one or two more restores, going backwards in time - again, remember to backup files or programs that may have changed since!
4. If all else fails, you may have irrevocably screwed your Windows 7 installation somehow and may have to reinstall it from scratch.

Comment: Yes. I sense what you're saying.

Comment: Interestingly enough, before I re-installed the OS, I tried System Restore, and found that it had been totally turned off and all my previous restore points were gone!

Comment: Ouch! I found out that some of my restore points got corrupted somehow. And guess which one did I need...